# How can I conditionally show a field in the node/add page?

Tags: nodes, 8

When users are in node/add/page, I want to show the body field when the title is not empty. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You want this when the page is viewed? or when someone is in the create a new page form?

Comment: When someone is in the create a new page form

Comment: @kiamlaluno can you re-open this so I can answer the question?

Comment: @no-sssweat answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default in Drupal 8 "Seven" is the admin theme.

(Assuming you're using Seven as your admin theme) In `/core/themes/seven/js` add/create *custom.js* file.

**custom.js**

```
(function ($) {

   $('#edit-body-wrapper').hide();

   (function Forever(){ 

     var title = $('#edit-title-0-value').val();

     if (title != '') { 
       $('#edit-body-wrapper').slideDown(1500); 
     } 
     // slides down and shows the body field in 1.5 secs if the title field is not empty

     else if (title == '') { 
       $('#edit-body-wrapper').slideUp(1500); 
     }
     // slides up and hides the body field in 1.5 secs if title is empty

   setTimeout(Forever, 1);

   })();

})(jQuery);
```

Now edit **seven.libraries.yml**

In the `node-form:` section add

```
  js:
    js/custom.js: {}
```

So it should look like this:

```
node-form:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    layout:
      css/layout/node-add.css: {}
  dependencies:
    - node/form
  js:
    js/custom.js: {}
```

**PS:** Don't forget to clear the cache to see changes.

Comment: **PPS:** When you go to add a page for a slight second you can see body field. If you don't want that, you can go to `/core/themes/seven/css/layout` and edit **node-add.css** and add `#edit-body-wrapper { display: none; }` and flush cache to see changes.